# Can you use the verbatim tag with Django 1.5 on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-templates

In my app.yaml file I have:

```
- name: django
   version: "1.5"
```

which I assume means, use Django 1.5. 1.5 includes the [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-verbatim) tag, but when I try to use it I get:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'verbatim' is not a valid tag library: Template library verbatim not found, tried google.appengine._internal.django.templatetags.verbatim
```

Any idea how to enable this feature or is it just not included with app engine, I am using 1.8.9. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it works.  When I tried to do this, I got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
...
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\django\template\__init__.py", line 333, in invalid_block_tag
    raise self.error(token, "Invalid block tag: '%s'" % command)
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'verbatim'
```

Looking at the source `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\_internal\django\__init__.py` you can see the version number in the first line:

`VERSION = (1, 2, 5, 'final', 0)`

This tells me that the appengine is using Django version 1.2.5 for the templating.  I do not know if these means you can deploy the app to production and it will somehow use 1.5, but I couldn't get it to work locally.  (Note that this was specifying Django 1.5 and Webapp 2.5.2 in my `app.yaml` using the Google App Engine Launcher 1.9.17)