# Verbatim-tag in Google App Engine not working

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, polymer, verbatim

I want to serve some `Polymer`-code via `Django` in a `Google App Engine`.

The problem is, that `Polymer` uses double curly braces, as does `Django`. In newer `Django` versions, one can use the `verbatim-tag`, but in the version used in `Google App Engine`, [this tag is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642321/can-you-use-the-verbatim-tag-with-django-1-5-on-app-engine).

Is there an alternative?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paulsmith/1313862

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `Jinja2` instead